# Добавление маршрутов и плейсмарков с помомью vow.all

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Подскажите, пожалуйста, получаю массив данных с сервера такого формата.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как с помощью vow.all добавить разного типа объекты на карту:

1. Если есть оба адреса то это маршрут (не мультимаршрут) (Route)
2. Если только один адрес то это точка (Placemark)

Comment: Не понятно в чем вопрос. Проверьте наличие обоих полей, если оба поля есть, то постройте маршрут, если нет то поставьте точку. Есть какие-то наработки, соберёте пример на jsfiddle?

Comment: Пример работы vow.all можно увидеть тут: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/tracks_compare

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ws3hy1o0/ Не пойму что дальше. Как это все передать в spread

Comment: Почему вы не хотите сделать так http://jsfiddle.net/cfsL5enq/ ?

Comment: У меня так сделано, но я столкнулся с другой проблемой. Я хочу при наведении мышкой на маршрут скрывать все другие маршруты и плейсмарки за исключением этого. Как это сделать, я не понимаю. Через колбек функцию если делать, то она будет вызваться в цикле 800 раз, т.е как дождаться добавления всех маршрутов и плейсмарков я не знаю.

Comment: Можно добавить объекты в коллекцию и скрывать всю коллекцию, как направление к размышлению http://jsfiddle.net/t2uxwhap/

Comment: А как дождаться тогда добавления всех маршрутов и плейсмарков. Ведь нужно добавить event на коллекцию, но если не дождаться то коллекция пустая будет. Кроме того, как скрывать всю коллекцию, ведь тогда скроется и наведённый элемент

Comment: Вы смотрели код который я прислал? Можно добавить эвент на коллекцию даже если она пустая, но когда добавится элемент в коллекцию то эвент будет отрабатывать и для добавленного элемента тоже.

Comment: А где вы собираетесь это использовать? Черезчур тяжелая карта получается и она будет быстро выедать лимиты.

Comment: Обычно не более 10 маршрутов будет на карте. Это тяжелая или нет?

Comment: Лимит 25000 запросов (геокодирований+маршрутов+панорам в день). Один маршрут построенный по адресу это 3 запроса. Одна точка поставленная по адресу это один запрос. Дальше умножаем на количество открытий этой карты и получаем итоговое число, нужно чтобы оно было меньше 25000 каждый день.

Comment: Посмотрел, неплохое решение. Только проблема в том, что при наведении на вейпоинт, скрывается все, кроме этого вейпоинта, грубо говоря скрываем все кроме таргета. Можно ли получить при наведении на таргет весь маршрут и оставлять его целиком?

Comment: Можно например так http://jsfiddle.net/ks2nb051/

Comment: Это уже мультимаршрут, он загрязняет визуально карту лишними вариантами маршрута, к тому же работает как-то тяжело (тормозит). Неужели нельзя вытащить маршрут используя Path или WayPoint в обычном маршруте (не мультимаршруте)

Comment: варианты маршрута можно отключить, подписи точек тоже можно отключить и получится тот-же роутер. Посмотреть всякие примеры можно тут https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/multiroute_driving и в документации. Роутер устаревшее решение и им не рекомендуется пользоваться.